# Multiple DC Voltage sources in parallel

Tags: power-supply, dc, parallel, bus

I'm building an alarm system (paradox EVO192 with ZX8 extension modules) and was hoping to have separate sections of the system each powered by it's own battery backed up power supply (something like this http://www.communica.co.za/catalog/Details/P0726831591).

The panel communicates and powers extension modules over a 4-wire bus - red/black/green/yellow. Unfortunately, if I just connect the panel to the module using yellow and green and then power the module independently using a different power supply, the panel doesn't see the module. The panel's red and black must also be tied to the module in order for them to communicate properly.

My question is, can I just add the extra power supplies in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your original attempt was that there was no reference for the two data lines that you hooked up. You need to share the ground connection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvZKys.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Module wiring.*

Connecting the V+ wires together would be a bad idea unless the system was designed for that.

Comment: Thanks, while waiting for an answer I started wondering if maybe they just needed a common ground. I've tried it and it worked!

Comment: It looks like an RS485 comms system or similar. Sometimes they'll work with the differential system between the data lines and without ground but it's not recommended. Thanks for accepting my answer.